# Jquery UI dialog to check form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-ui, form-submit

I have sat here and fiddled with multiple different examples and none work. What I am trying to do is take a form that has three buttons (save, cancel, and delete). The delete button needs to come up with a prompt asking if the user is sure. Here is the code i have so far... and have tried multiple examples... none are working for me.

```
<form id="templateEdit" method="post" action="/admin/template/{{ var temp }}/{{ var page }}">
<div class="control right"><input type="submit" name="save" value="submit" /><input type="submit" name="cancel" value="cancel" /><input type="submit" name="delete" id="delete" value="delete" /></div>
<textarea name="editor" class="ckeditor">{{ var contents }}</textarea>
</form>
```

The following code is in a document ready Jquery function:

```
$("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                resizable: false,
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Yes": function () {
                        $('#templateEdit').off("submit").submit();
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    "No": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });

            $('#templateEdit').submit(function (event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                $('#dialog-confirm').dialog('open');

            });
```

Edit: The no button does work, but yes button is now submitting, but no post data is getting sent with submit.

Update: So this is how I have fixed my issue completly:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                resizable: false,
                autoOpen: false,
                modal: true,
                width: 500,
                buttons: {
                    "Yes": function () {
                        $("#templateEdit").attr('action', "/admin/templates.php?temp={{ var temp }}&page={{ var page }}&action=delete");
                        $('#templateEdit').get(0).submit();
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    },
                    "No": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });

            $('#delete').click(function (event) {
                $("#dialog-confirm").dialog("open");
                event.preventDefault();
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a spelling mistake in the selector `temaplteEdit` instead of `templateEdit`

You need to rename the button with name `submit`

```
<input type="submit" name="save" value="submit" />
```

then call

```
$('#templateEdit').get(0).submit();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/eBN9A/)

or

```
$('#templateEdit').off('submit').submit();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/V6RDN/)

Update: [image]

Comment: Just fixed this issue, thank you for showing it. However, that did not fix the problem on the whole... The no button works, but Yes does not continue form submission.

Comment: Just changed my input button, and now form submission kinda works... but my php is not gathering the post data from the submit button.

Comment: @JamesRay can you check the post request data using your browser's developer tools?

Comment: According to Google > inspect Element > network the only post data is my html page.  here is the Error i am getting on submission: 

    Notice: Undefined index: save in C:\Users\James\Desktop\Dropbox\htdocs\CMS\admin\templates.php on line 43

     Notice: Undefined index: cancel in C:\Users\James\Desktop\Dropbox\htdocs\CMS\admin\templates.php on line 47

    Notice: Undefined index: delete in C:\Users\James\Desktop\Dropbox\htdocs\CMS\admin\templates.php on line 49

Comment: @JamesRay that is the response... you need to look at the `headers` tab under `network`... there will be a section called `FormData`.. that is the data submitted to the server

Comment: The only thing getting submitted is the textfield (editor), but it doesn't tell me which button was pressed to submit that information.

Comment: @JamesRay the value of the submit button will be submitted only if the submission was triggered by pressing that button... in this case it is not because we are preventing the actual submit and then triggering it manually... the solution will be is to use a hidden input control

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am going to go the route of when delete button is clicked to change form url. But these posts help get me there.